# celery_1 | ImportError: No module named 'hh_ru_django'

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker, docker-compose, django-celery

Watched many tutorials with dockerize celery + django, did like in the video.I think the problem is in docker-compose file, but i didn't found the solution.It took to much time, and i couldn't solve the problem.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /usr/src/hh_ru_django
COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/hh_ru_django/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /usr/src/hh_ru_django
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  pgdb:
    image: postgres
    container_name: pgdb
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  django:
    build: .
    container_name: django
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/hh_ru_django
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
      - DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1
      - CELERY_BROKER=redis://redis:6379/0/
    depends_on:
      - pgdb
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
        - '6379:6379'
  celery:
    image: celery
    command: celery worker -A hh_ru_django --loglevel=info
    volumes:
        - .:/usr/src/hh_ru_django
    depends_on:
        - django
        - redis
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

hh_ru_django/celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os

from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "hh_ru_django.settings")

app = Celery("hh_ru_django")

app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")

app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

hh_ru_django/settings.py just the variables with broker

```
"""
Django settings for hh_ru_django project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '$eg8idk$k-6m(9#8-23fk_ta5ga$@!^ex6mqut_%+-d)2=lm!_'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ads.apps.AdsConfig',
    'hh_ru_django'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'hh_ru_django.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'hh_ru_django.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'pgdb',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


CELERY_BROKER = os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER", "redis://redis:6479/0")
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER", "redis://redis:6479/0")
```

The traceback

```
celery_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
celery_1  |   File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
celery_1  |     sys.exit(main())
celery_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
celery_1  |     main()
celery_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main
celery_1  |     cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
celery_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 793, in execute_from_commandline
celery_1  |     super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
celery_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 309, in execute_from_commandline
celery_1  |     argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
celery_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 469, in setup_app_from_commandline
celery_1  |     self.app = self.find_app(app)
celery_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 489, in find_app
celery_1  |     return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
celery_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 235, in find_app
celery_1  |     sym = symbol_by_name(app, imp=imp)
celery_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 492, in symbol_by_name
celery_1  |     return symbol_by_name(name, imp=imp)
celery_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 96, in symbol_by_name
celery_1  |     module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
celery_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 101, in import_from_cwd
celery_1  |     return imp(module, package=package)
celery_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
celery_1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
celery_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
celery_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
celery_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
celery_1  | ImportError: No module named 'hh_ru_django'
```

Project tree

```
├── ads
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tasks.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── hh_ru_django
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── celery.py
│   ├── __init__.py 
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
└── requirements.txt
```

Comment: How did you start your django project?

Comment: with command docker-compose run django django-admin startproject hh_ru_django .

Comment: Why your hh_ru_django/settings.py contains only two lines? Or it is a part of your settings.py?

Comment: This error message usually means that app is not installed. In your case it means that `hh_ru_django` not installed.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it is a part of file. hh_ru_django is core project's app. It is with file settings. Where can i install it? I have just tried to add it to installed apps, but it didn't help.

Comment: Added full settings.py file

Comment: Added traceback

Comment: Remove `hh_ru_django` from `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Removed, but without hh_ru_django in installed apps python shows the same problem.

Comment: Added project tree

Comment: It didn't help.The same issue

Comment: What does `hh_ru_django>__init__.py` contain?

Comment: from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)

Comment: See also Django 3.1 does't support python3.5. [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/#python-compatibility](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/#python-compatibility)

Comment: Solved it , I wrote build: . instead of image:celery